# Rake aborted, I think it is in reference to a enum I have in my /lib folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my seeds.rb file I have:

```
user = User.new(
   :user_type => UserTypes.MEMBER

)
```

I get an error:

```
rake aborted!
Expected /..../lib/user_types.rb to define UserTypes


module SomeName

   class UserTypes
       MEMBER = 1,
       BLAHBALH = 2
   end

end
```

Do I need an include or require at the top of the file?

Comment: If your UserTypes class in the SomeName module, why don't you write SomeName::UserTypes.MEMBER?

Comment: how about working on that acceptance rating?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not an `include`, you need the full classname (incl. modules). You might also need to move the file to `lib/some_name/user_types.rb` (this you can avoid by using an explicit `require`).

```
user = User.new(
   :user_type => SomeName::UserTypes::MEMBER
)
```